# what am i doing wrong and how can i improve my code

Tags: c, move

can someone explain me why if i press s button or d button it throws me segmetation fault but with a button and w button it works fine.it is just a function to move player p in a square just like snake.

```
void move(){

    int i;
    int j;
    char choice;

    scanf("%s",&choice);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            if(maze[i][j] == 'p' && choice == 'a') {
                char tmp =  maze[i][j];
                maze[i][j] = maze[i][j-1];
                maze[i][j-1] = tmp;
            }

            if(maze[i][j] == 'p' && choice == 'w'){
                char tmp =  maze[i][j];
                maze[i][j] = maze[i-1][j];
                maze[i-1][j] = tmp;
            }

            if(maze[i][j] == 'p' && choice == 'd') {
                char tmp = maze[i][j];
                maze[i][j] = maze[i][j+1];
                maze[i][j+1] = tmp;
            }

            if(maze[i][j] == 'p' && choice == 's') {
                char tmp =  maze[i][j];
                maze[i][j] = maze[i+1][j];
                maze[i+1][j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&choice);`- please read the documentation of `scanf` about the difference between `%c` and `%s`. You are using the wrong one so your code has *undefined behavior*

Comment: I don't think this would cause a segfault, but you should be protecting yourself from overflowing your array.  For example, what if `i` is zero and you run `maze[i-1][j] = tmp;`?

Comment: ...similarly `maze[i][j-1]` and `maze[i][j+1]` look set to break the array bounds, at the beginning and end of the iterations of `j`.

Comment: yeah ok with %s but problem still remains.In order to move my character i change his seat with maze[i-1][j](if choice == w(up)).so how may i solve this?

Comment: What if i== row-1, j == col-1, maze[i][j] == 'p' and you hit 'd'?  It will advance past the end of the array and probably cause a segfault.  You need to add protection to your maze runner so that it ignores input off the edge of the maze.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and welcome to programming!

Per related comments, the segfault is most likely due to overrunning the bounds of your `maze[][]` array.  You ask in a couple of your comments how you can deal with this situation.

In the interest of providing the *most constructive* advice, instead of giving you code, I'm going to ask a question:

**How, in programming, do we cause something to happen or not happen under specific conditions?**

So, describe for yourself the conditions under which you should *not* be making references such as `i + 1` or `j - 1`, and then add corresponding logic to your code.

I also encourage you to ask yourself:

**How many times does my `move()` function alter the `maze[][]` for a single input?**

Write down your answer, and then add output statements, or for example a `show()` function that prints out the total current state of `maze[][]`, in the inner-most part of your loops in `move()`.  See if your expected answer matches your actual output.

---

Regarding your description of this program that when you :

> "press s button or d button it throws me segmentation fault but with a button and w button it works fine"

... I would say that it only *appears* to be working when you press the `a` button or the `w` button.  In fact, whenever you reference outside the bounds of an array (which might happen no matter which of `w`, `a`, `s`, or `d` is pressed), the behavior is **undefined**.  So, by chance, the way the program gets compiled (for you, at a particular time) might not segfault right away when pressing `w`.  When you access outside the bounds of an array, you might access memory that is okay to access, and it will *seem* to work; but you might access memory that is off limits to your process, and it will segfault.

Bugs related to **undefined behavior** can be the most subtle to deal with.  Logic to serve as guardrails, and debug output statements to show actual value changes can help quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the bat this code is incorrect

```
char choice;

scanf("%s",&choice);
```

Choice is one character - how can it hold a string of multiple characters?

This would be better

```
char choice[101];

scanf("%100s", choice);
```

Would enable a string of up to 100 characters

The 101 - nothing related to George Orwell - enables the null character to be added

You should also check the return value from `scanf`. Please read the manual page for `scanf`

BTW - I have not got to the read the rest of the code

Comment: thx Ed heal i solve this(my bad) but problem still remains for the rest of the code